# Is it possible to set the Core Data custom class variable in code?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

if you use an attribute of type transformable you can set a correspoding custom class which describes the type of the saved value.
In the .xcdatamodeld this is pretty easily accomplished as you can see in the picture.
[image]

So is it possible to access this custom class property through the NSAttributeDescription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there. It's the `attributeValueClassName` property on `NSAttributeDescription`.

Keep in mind that you can only change the data model **before** you use it to load a persistent store. That means before calling `loadPersistentStores()` or `addPersistentStore(ofType:configurationName:at:options:)`. If you attempt to modify the data model after this, your app will crash. Although data models are mutable, that mutability can only be used when no persistent stores have been loaded.